# Process.whereis(:user) returns a pid. What is this pid?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

In Elixir's repl `iex` when I enter `Process.whereis(:user)` it returns a `pid`. What is this `:user` process? What does it do? What is it's state?

It seems to be permanently blocked or sleeping as I have not been able to get a response with `:user |> Process.whereis() |> :sys.get_state()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the standard I/O server in Erlang/OTP, the process that does the I/O for the user interface(s).

The (somewhat brief) documentation is here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/user.html

If you would like to verify that this is in fact where the `user` process is registered, look here: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/user.erl#L45